# God as Universal religion, humanity as prayer

Tags: gods

Every time I come across a religious scripts on how to meditate on gods name, first that comes in why can't we all come together as one. Why can't we project God & Humanity above all and focus on verses or sayings from different religious scripts that unites us, brings us together. Is it so difficult?

I am not much into religious activities or rituals,but yes I had the privilege of visiting various worship place, including churches, temples, dargahs, gurdwaras. I still go whenever I get chance.

All I do is meditation. I've read this blog and found you guys have very good knowledge of religious scripts.

And curiosity bug bit me, can we find verses from different religious books with simlar meaning. I beleive we can, or I should say "you guys can". You're really good at it as you all are thoroughly knowledgeable.

So guys it's my humble request let's project God's universalism and humanity, love and compassion. We already have had enough of this religious intolerance issues recently. Let's work towards peace, all we have is one home planet - earth.

God bless you all

Comment: I think the question is "can we post verses from various religious books with similar meaning". Correct? If yes, then here is a problem. All the people on this site are good at hinduism. But we may not know much about Christianity or Islam or Buddhism. If you ask a question on Buddhism.SE, they may be experts in Buddhism, but not necessarily in Hinduism or Zorastrianism. This is the problem with society at large. Everybody knows their religion (their side of the picture), but to really appreciate the Unity of all religions, one has to read other religious books! Good question